# How can I change the size of the Visual Studio clipboard ring?

Tags: visual-studio

The clipboard ring stores the last 20 cut/copies.  It can only be navigated forward.  The clipboard ring toolbox was removed several years ago.  So the only way to find the text I need is to scroll through each item with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Making bulk modifications with a few one-offs mixed in leads to a lot of cycling through the entire ring because I forgot the state of the ring's LIFO stack and skipped past what I wanted on accident.  Is there any way to reduce the ring size to something usable or an extension that works well and is not ReSharper?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [ClipboardHistory](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/62040158-8ae2-4f87-8e09-0a3a812088ec) extension.